# Convoy Spare Capacity

Tags: c

Consider a conveyor belt on which many items are loaded. As the items come off the belt, they are loaded onto delivery trucks. All trucks are the same and they can carry items up to a specific maximum weight (called the capacity of the truck). Items are numbered from 1 and are of various weights.
The items must be loaded sequentially onto the trucks, i.e., items 1 to N (for some N) go on the first truck, items N+1, …, M (for some M) go on the second truck, and so on. Not all trucks will be loaded to their full capacity, of course, but it is guaranteed that no single item is too heavy for a truck.
We can load the trucks in a greedy manner (load as many items as you can on this truck and when the next item does not fit, start a new truck) but this may lead to an unbalanced distribution of the items among the trucks.

Define the spare capacity of the convoy as the sum of squares of the unused capacity of each truck in the convoy. We want to load the trucks in such a way to minimize the spare capacity of the convoy.

Given the capacity, c, of the trucks and sequence of weights of the items, how many items should each truck carry, and how many trucks are required?

The first line of data gives the value of c and the number of items, n (<= 1000). Subsequent lines contain n values, the weights of the items, in order. Some sample data are:

```
6  5
1  2  3 
1  1
```

Output: on the first line, print the number of trucks required. On the second line, print the number of items on each truck, starting with the number of items on the first truck, followed by the number of items on the second truck, and so on. On the last line print the spare capacity of the convoy. For the above data, you should output:

```
2
2  3
10
```

Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I love academic problems, "We want to load the trucks in such a way to minimize the spare capacity of the convoy." I imagine most corporations would want to minimize the number of driver-hours necessary for the problem -- if you could keep three drivers home for the day by simply paying one driver one hour of overtime, that's the obvious answer. :)

Comment: You may wish to start your research at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that the question is a knapsack problem but the parts that throw me off is that there are multiple, knapsacks(trucks) of the same size and have to be filled sequentially and the way each is filled has a direct effect on the spare capacity. Was also thinking along the lines of parenthesization but wasn't really sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Nice, whomever your lecturer or tutor is they have a sense of humour, they have given you a very hard problem to solve, infact it is NP-complete to solve exactly. This is an instance of the [Knapsac Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) if I am not mistaken. Read the wikipedia page and alot of reasearch on it; there are plenty of algorithms out there that you can look at and implement that can be tailored to your exact problem space.

Comment: I doubt this is a homework problem. Looks like a competition problem from USACO: http://www.uwp.edu/sws/usaco/

Comment: When I was in school, we didn't call that a "sense of humour". :-)

Comment: trust me it is a homework problem that was given a minimum of one week to complete. Our lecturer has a great sense of humor :D. The only problem is that he's the only one who's ever laughing :(

Comment: "NP-complete" does not mean that you cannot write an algorithm/program for it. I do not see anything wrong or twisted in asking students to implement an algorithm for an NP-complete problem.

Comment: @Pascal neither do I, I just think that compared to other problems this one is particularly hard to get right thus I don't think it is twisted at all. I literally do think it is funny that somebody has to solve it to the best of their ability when the lecturer knows full well that they can easily create input that will stump the best of algorithms.